# What kind of animation goes into the 'slide to unlock' text on a iphone?

Tags: iphone, objective-c

I am just getting a hold on how controllers/views work on the iphone.

I want to learn some basic animation, like how the text on the iphone is animated when you need to unlock the phone it says 'slide to unlock'.

Are there any tutorials on basic animations you guys can guide me to that do something similar?

Comment: You can make an inverted image (use the text as transparent, and the "empty space" as black) and move a radial gradient from left to right.

Comment: possible duplicate of [iPhone "slide to unlock" animation](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/438046/iphone-slide-to-unlock-animation)

Answer (score 2):

Check out this similar question on SO: [Slide To Unlock Animation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/438046/iphone-slide-to-unlock-animation).

There are also a few nice examples that demonstrate how to build the entire view. Try searching on `github` or `bitbucket`.