# Slide finger from button to another button in iPhone

Tags: iphone

I am beginner in iPhone development. How can we drag from one button to another button using finger? I used `touchMoved` but it's not working. Is it possible?

Thank you.

Comment: Can you give some detailed information.

Comment: are you trying to achieve iPhone slide lock kind of thing?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this -

```
![- (void)create_Custom_UISlider
{
    CGRect frame = CGRectMake(10.0, 50.0, 300, 52.0);
    CGRect thumb = CGRectMake(0.0, 0.0, 71.0, 47.0);
    customSlider = [[UISlider alloc] initWithFrame:frame];
    [customSlider addTarget:self action:@selector(sliderAction:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
    // in case the parent view draws with a custom color or gradient, use a transparent color
    customSlider.backgroundColor = [UIColor clearColor];    
    UIImage *stetchLeftTrack = [[UIImage imageNamed:@"customTrack.png"]
                                stretchableImageWithLeftCapWidth:10.0 topCapHeight:0.0];
    UIImage *stetchRightTrack = [[UIImage imageNamed:@"customTrack.png"]
                                 stretchableImageWithLeftCapWidth:10.0 topCapHeight:0.0];
    [customSlider setThumbImage: [UIImage imageNamed:@"customThumb_off.png"] forState:UIControlStateNormal];
    [customSlider setMinimumTrackImage:stetchLeftTrack forState:UIControlStateNormal];
    [customSlider setMaximumTrackImage:stetchRightTrack forState:UIControlStateNormal];
    [customSlider thumbRectForBounds: thumb trackRect: frame value: customSlider.value];
    customSlider.minimumValue = 0.0;
    customSlider.maximumValue = 1.0;
    customSlider.continuous = YES;
    customSlider.value = 0.0;
}


- (void) sliderAction: (UISlider *) sender
{
    if (customSlider.value != 1.0)  //if the value is not the max, slide this bad boy back to zero
    {
        [sender setValue: 0 animated: YES];
    }
    else {  
               if (customSlider.value == 1.0)  //if the value is max, slide this bad boy back to zero and execute code
    {
        [sender setValue: 0 animated: NO];
        }
                // the rest of your code here.
        }
}][1]
```

[image]
[image]

Also have a look on this Question - [iPhone "slide to unlock" animation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/438046/iphone-slide-to-unlock-animation)

Comment: I am trying to do nine dot pattern lock. Anyone can help me?

Answer (score 0):

### Yes it possible. first you put this method :..........

```
- (void)touchesBegan:(NSSet *)touches withEvent:(UIEvent *)event{
    UITouch *touch = [[event allTouches] anyObject];

btn addTarget:self action:@selector(wasDragged:withEvent:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchDragInside];

}


and

- (void)wasDragged:(UIButton *)button withEvent:(UIEvent *)event
{
 scroll.frame=CGRectMake(self.scroll.frame.origin.x, self.scroll.frame.origin.y, self.scroll.frame.size.width+1800, self.scroll.frame.size.height);
 scroll.contentSize=CGSizeMake(2000,1200);
 scroll.backgroundColor=[UIColor clearColor];
 UITouch *touch = [[event touchesForView:button] anyObject];

 NSLog(@"%d",button.frame.origin.x);

 CGPoint previousLocation = [touch previousLocationInView:button];
 CGPoint location = [touch locationInView:button];

 CGFloat delta_x = location.x - previousLocation.x;
 CGFloat delta_y = location.y - previousLocation.y;


  button.center = CGPointMake(button.center.x + delta_x,
         button.center.y + delta_y);

}
```

Comment: scroll.frame=CGRectMake(self.scroll.frame.origin.x, self.scroll.frame.origin.y, self.scroll.frame.size.width+1800, self.scroll.frame.size.height);