# Shimmer animation in IOS?

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, animation

I want to make a shimmer animation on UIView just like iPhone "slide to unlock" view ,any one have any idea ? I used the this code [iPhone shine animation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6564700/iphone-shine-animation) but it just passes a white gradient above the view.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Facebook recreated this effect a long while ago and open sourced it:

https://github.com/facebook/Shimmer

Comment: I tried this one and open the example project but it give me error.<FBShimmering/FBShimmeringView.h> this file not found

Comment: Make sure you open the `.xcworkspace` file, not the `.xcodeproj` files. And make sure that neither of the `.xcodeproj` files are open whilst the `.xcworkspace` file is open.

Comment: its build successfully but nothing is heaping I mean simulator does not open, I think i am doing some kind a foolish thing but I can not find out.

Comment: ohh sorry i was just building the framework , now its working thanks!. its exactly what I Want.