# How to Highlight word of UILabel in iphone

Tags: iphone

I am loading Lyrics of song on UILabel With Timer. Now I want to highlight Each word of that label with different color. How can I do this ?

I am showing lyrics like this

```
- (void)setCurrentAudioProgress:(NSTimeInterval)time duration:(NSTimeInterval)duration
{
    float progress = time/duration;
    long currentPlaybackTime = audioPlayer.currentTime;
    long remainingTime = (duration-time);

    int remainingHours = (remainingTime /3600);

    int remainingMinutes = ((remainingTime /60 -remainingHours*60));

    int remainingSeconds = (remainingTime %60);


    int currentHours = (currentPlaybackTime / 3600);

    int currentMinutes = ((currentPlaybackTime / 60) - currentHours*60);
    int currentSeconds = (currentPlaybackTime % 60);

    currentTimeLabel.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%i:%02d:%02d", currentHours, currentMinutes, currentSeconds];

    remainingTimeLabel.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%i.%02d.%02d", remainingHours    , remainingMinutes, remainingSeconds];

    [progressView setProgress:progress];

    for (int i = 0; i<[lyricsArray count]; i++) {

        NSString  *lyricsTime = [[lyricsArray objectAtIndex:i]valueForKey:@"startTime" ] ;

        if ([currentTimeLabel.text isEqualToString:lyricsTime]) {

            songLyricsLabel.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@",[[lyricsArray objectAtIndex:i]valueForKey:@"songLyrics" ]];         
         }            
    }          
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You have to use the trick some thing like this one label doesn't support the highlighting

[iPhone "slide to unlock" animation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/438046/iphone-slide-to-unlock-animation)

Answer (score 0):

You can use following whenever you want to highlight the label text then just add the following lines for respective label

```
        label.highlighted = YES;
label.highlightedTextColor = [UIColor blueColor];
```

for different color you can add an array with color names and select randomly....

Comment: I want to highlight each word of UILAbel

Comment: When you set the label.highlighted = YES then it will highlight whole text of label with assigned color. But if you want to highlight each word with different color then it will not work, you need to add a function which will take each character one by one and will set the color for it....