# List examples of how to "briefly draw attention" to an object on screen in iOS?

Tags: objective-c, ios

In iOS, how can one **briefly draw attention** to an object on screen? Suppose, create a brief glow or cause a shadow to appear and then disappear?

For the purposes of this question, let's define "object on screen" as an instance of UIImageView.

Also, if possible provide an example of how to draw attention to a button.

Comment: You can use implicit animation. First disable implicit animation, and set the property that you want to animate to the "draw attention" state (brighter background? red border?). The re-enable animation, set the property back to the normal level, and return. Your object will immediately go to the "highlighted" state, and then slowly animate back to normal.

Comment: @dasblinkenlight, could you please provide an example?

Comment: The kind of example depends on your object: please provide more details about it. Is it a `UIImageView`, a `UIButton`, a `CALayer`, etc.? The code would be slightly different for different kinds of objects.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

```
[UIView beginAnimations:nil context:NULL];
[UIView setAnimationDuration:0.1f];
yourView.transform = CGAffineTransformMakeScale(1.1, 1.1);
[UIView commitAnimations];
```

Or, of course the same thing with a block animations. And after the attention got away from your view you can use :

```
[UIView beginAnimations:nil context:NULL];
[UIView setAnimationDuration:0.1f];
yourView.transform = CGAffineTransformIdentity;
[UIView commitAnimations];
```

Answer (score 17):

Most people list code, but I'm sticking to describing some examples;

- I've seen objects briefly grow and shrink back to their normal size to draw attention
- Bejeweled (a Popcap game) lets diamonds briefly 'shine' (as if sunlight passed over it) to give you a subtle hint
- I've seen certain applications use a hand or a fictive character point to a certain object briefly

And of course, you could always introduce a talking paperclip to tell you what's what.
[image]

Answer (score 8):

Here is a simple hop animation...

```
- (void)drawAttn
{
float jumpHeight = 20.0;

CGPoint originalPoint = objectForAttn.center;
CGPoint jumpPoint = CGPointMake(objectForAttn.center.x, objectForAttn.center.y - jumpHeight);
    [UIView animateWithDuration:0.20 delay:0.0 options:UIViewAnimationOptionAutoreverse animations:^{
        [objectForAttn setCenter:jumpPoint];

    } completion:^(BOOL finished) {
        /* do other stuff after hop */
    }];
}
```

Answer (score 4):

My app QCount (free in the store, tap a "wrong" number 3 times) uses a fade animation as follows:

(note I wrote this when I was REALLY new to iOS, so there is probably a more compact way to write it)

```
    aLabel = // a UILabel I get from somewhere
    aColor = aLabel.backgroundColor;
    [UIView animateWithDuration:0.2
                          delay: 0.0
                        options: UIViewAnimationOptionCurveEaseOut
                     animations:^{
                         aLabel.alpha = 0.0;
                     }
                     completion:^(BOOL finished){
                         // Wait .2 seconds and then fade in the view
                         [UIView animateWithDuration:.2
                                               delay: 0.0
                                             options:UIViewAnimationOptionCurveEaseIn
                                          animations:^{
                                                    aLabel.alpha = 1.0;
                                          }
                                          completion:nil];
                     }];
```

Comment: You could take out the delay and the second completion block (nil) to make it a bit smaller quickly. Other than that I think it's fine.

Comment: Use UIViewAnimationOptionAutoreverse for your option and the alpha will change back automatically.

Answer (score 4):

There are lots of options: hopping, underlining, vibrating, blinking, rotating, scaling, endarkening around, and their combinations.

But IMO, shine effect on "slide to unlock" text is excellent.

You can check it out here:
[iPhone "slide to unlock" animation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/438046/iphone-slide-to-unlock-animation)

Answer (score 0):

I wanted to draw attention to a label whose value had changed. This simple animation produces a nice 'I've changed' animation...

```
    //copy the label
    UILabel *newPageLabel = [[UILabel alloc] initWithFrame:_countLabel.frame];
    [newPageLabel setFrame:CGRectOffset(newPageLabel.frame, 0, 0)];
    newPageLabel.text = _countLabel.text;
    newPageLabel.textAlignment = _countLabel.textAlignment;
    newPageLabel.backgroundColor = _countLabel.backgroundColor;
    newPageLabel.textColor = _countLabel.textColor;
    newPageLabel.font = _countLabel.font;

    //scale and fade out the copied label
    [self.navigationController.toolbar addSubview:newPageLabel];
    [UIView animateWithDuration:0.5
                          delay:0.0
                        options:UIViewAnimationOptionLayoutSubviews
                     animations:^{
                         newPageLabel.transform = CGAffineTransformMakeScale(2,2);
                         newPageLabel.alpha = 0;
                     }
                     completion:^(BOOL finished){
                         [newPageLabel removeFromSuperview];
                     }
     ];
```