# How do I reverse my "slide to unlock" style text?

Tags: ios, objective-c, core-animation

I've been able to use code from another stack overflow question ([iPhone "slide to unlock" animation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/438046/iphone-slide-to-unlock-animation)) to make some text pulse in the "slide to unlock" style. At the moment, the mask moves from the left to the right. I'd like to reverse it so that instead of having it pulse from left to right, it pulses from right to left.

I've fiddled around with the code, trying to figure out how to reverse it but nothing I've done has got it to work properly! Everything I thought would work, hasn't.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

```
self.view.layer.backgroundColor = [[UIColor blackColor] CGColor];

CGFloat textWidth = 320;
CGFloat textHeight = 76;

CALayer *textLayer = [CALayer layer];
textLayer.contents = (id)[self.MYSLIDEIMAGE.image CGImage];
textLayer.frame = CGRectMake(-69.0f, 350.0f, textWidth, textHeight);

CALayer *maskLayer = [CALayer layer];

// Mask image ends with 0.15 opacity on both sides. Set the background color of the layer
// to the same value so the layer can extend the mask image.
maskLayer.backgroundColor = [[UIColor colorWithRed:0.0f green:0.0f blue:0.0f alpha:0.1f] CGColor];
maskLayer.contents = (id)[[UIImage imageNamed:@"Mask.png"] CGImage];

// Center the mask image on twice the width of the text layer, so it starts to the left
// of the text layer and moves to its right when we translate it by width.
maskLayer.contentsGravity = kCAGravityCenter;
maskLayer.frame = CGRectMake(-textWidth +50, 0.0f, textWidth * 2, textHeight);

// Animate the mask layer's horizontal position
CABasicAnimation *maskAnim = [CABasicAnimation animationWithKeyPath:@"position.x"];
maskAnim.byValue = [NSNumber numberWithFloat:textWidth -50];
maskAnim.repeatCount = HUGE_VALF;
maskAnim.duration = 2.8f;
[maskLayer addAnimation:maskAnim forKey:@"slideAnim"];
textLayer.mask = maskLayer;
[self.view.layer addSublayer:textLayer];
```

Comment: Please add link to the referenced stack overflow question. Side note: be careful with this style of animation. Apple is likely to reject your app if you unreasonably replicate some distinctive UI elements, like the "Slide to unlock" control.

Comment: Thanks for the heads-up about Apple possibly rejecting it. I'll keep that in mind.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Currently you're using `byValue` on the animation which means "start from where you are (zero) and go to this position". Instead, you can use `fromValue` and `toValue` to specify exactly where the animation should start and end. In this way you can control the direction.