# Creating a "Slide to power off" like slider on iOS

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, swift, cocoa-touch

I'm trying to create a slider like this:

[image: Slider]

Is there a UI Element I can use in order to achieve this? Or another way?

Comment: try this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/438046/iphone-slide-to-unlock-animation

Answer (score 5, accepted):

No, there is no direct UIElement available which will give the desired effect. 
If you plan to release the app on AppStore I would suggest do not try to replicate slide to unlock / power off.

I had a app rejected exactly for this reason. Following is the rejection reason as given by Apple.

> Specifically, the Slide to Start element is not appropriate
>   and not in compliance with the App Store Review Guidelines as it is
>   too similar to the iOS Slide to Unlock UI. While we understand this
>   specific UI element is not present in the current version of iOS, it
>   is still not appropriate to include it in your app.

I had this same UIElement approved in an earlier version but got rejected during an update. So there is a small chance it gets over looked.

Comment: How close was your Slide to Start to the iOS Slide to Unlock UI? Do you have a screenshot?

Comment: Amazon's iOS app has "Swipe to buy" but has not been rejected. I believe it is not the Slide to Start element itself that Apple reviewers consider inappropriate, but the shape that resembles the iOS UI. FYI, Amazon's "Swipe to buy" slide button is a square, not a circle.